# Keeping Object in Session will Occupy Heap Size or Not

Tags: java, session, groovy

I am dealing with large number of records around 100K so to sort out a time consumption issue I am keeping those records in session. I want to know whether keeping object in session will occupy memory of heap or not.

I tried this

```
long heapSizeBefore = Runtime.getRuntime().freeMemory()
session.expandDataList = returnMap[0]
session.expandDataListSize = returnMap[3]
session.rootParentsFrExpand = returnMap[1]
session.parentListFrExpand = returnMap[2]
long heapSizeAfter = Runtime.getRuntime().freeMemory();
long size = heapSizeAfter - heapSizeBefore
println 'size--------- ' + size // size--------- 0
```

Which is giving difference `0` so should I consider `keeping object in session` will `not occupy` any `heap size`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your methodology is incorrect. The memory for the `returnMap` object is already allocated before you start. Adding more references to it won't increase the memory usage, but it can stop it being decreased by preventing garbage collection.

Comment: Ok. So even I don't keep in session my heap size will be same. but issue is that it wont allow to gc

Comment: GC can't happen until there are no more references, whatever that means in your application.